# Writing From a Specific Directory to Another Specific Directory Using Ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Let say I had a stack of images in a given directory with a path X all of which had 12 digit padding as their names (each one looks like XXXXXXXXXXXX_us.jpeg where X is a number). If I wanted to take the images in this stack and write them to an MP4 in a directory with path Y at a framerate of 40 fps how would I do that using cmd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow) and [here](https://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#How-do-I-encode-single-pictures-into-movies_003f).

First `cd` into path `X`, then run a command like this one (you may have to tweak it):

```
ffmpeg -framerate 40 -i %12d_us.jpeg /Y/output.mp4
```